Problem with booting ubuntu 20.04
I have a problem with starting ubuntu dual boot laptop, windows starts and works fine. First it was that it booted into a screen with green OK (photo of the screen https://imgur.com/a/f19kt3f) and would be stuck on that screen. After that i could go to another screen with ctrl alt f5, and then try somethings. After i purged the nvidia drivers and rebooted it went to the purple login screen, but when I log in it goes to a black screen for a spitsecond and then back to the purple login screen.
Hope someone can help.
